# Limiting Common Table Recursion

Tags: mysql, recursive

I am trying to migrate from Oracle to MariaDB. At the moment, we are facing an issue with the following Oracle code.

```
 SELECT id,MK, pid,AFI 
   FROM M A 
  WHERE LEVEL <= 2 -- limiting iterations here
  START WITH pid = 1 
CONNECT BY Pid = PRIOR id;
```

We have used recursive common expression table but we are unable to restrict the number of iterations to 2 (`LEVEL <= 2`). We don't want to set the system variables like `cte_max_recursion_depth`. How else can we limit recursion depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mysql/mariadb syntax should be the next:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
  ( SELECT 1 AS lvl -- UDV initialization
         , A.id
         , A.MK
         , A.pid
         , A.AFI -- initial portion
      FROM M AS A 
     WHERE A.pid = 1

     UNION

    SELECT cte.lvl + 1 AS lvl -- UDV increment on each iteration
         , z.id
         , z.MK
         , z.pid
         , z.AFI -- recursive portion
      FROM cte -- referring to the already gathered recursion
      JOIN M AS z ON z.pid = cte.id
      WHERE lvl <= 2  -- Supa's amendment
  )
SELECT *
  FROM cte 
-- WHERE lvl <= 2 -- wrong place
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It has solved the problem for us.

Comment: @SaivishnuSR: if that answer solved your problem, then accept the answer, so that the question is marked as resolved

Answer (score 4):

Please note while @Kondybas' answer will produce expected results on correct data sets it **will NOT restrict** the number of iterations.

All rows will still be read but only 2 of them will be returned. That means:

1. Drop in performance
2. You will NOT avoid infinite loops that way!

If there is a loop in the tree of `pid`-`id` links in the table data due to some mistake such query can last forever (which might event corrupt the entire server by flooding the disk with endless temporary result data - checked in MariaDB 10.3.15.)

So you have to put a restricting condition inside the `WITH` clause as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
  ( SELECT 1 AS lvl -- UDV initialization
         , A.id
         , A.MK
         , A.pid
         , A.AFI -- initial portion
      FROM M AS A 
     WHERE A.pid = 1

     UNION

    SELECT cte.lvl + 1 AS lvl -- UDV increment on each iteration
         , z.id
         , z.MK
         , z.pid
         , z.AFI -- recursive portion
      FROM cte -- referring to the already gathered recursion
      JOIN M AS z ON z.pid = cte.id
      WHERE cte.lvl < 2        -- *** the correct condition ***
  )
SELECT *
  FROM cte 
;
```

P.S. I guess it is also a good idea to set [max_recursive_iterations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_recursive_iterations) to some reachable value like 10000 to prevent MariaDB from getting unresponsive.

Comment: A very good point! Thanks!